# Surely someone with explosives can take anything as a hostage?

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, earth-like

You're a police officer. A few minutes back, your walkie-talkie crackled and you were told that the Criminals (an infamous group of criminals whose identities are unknown) have struck again and this time, their target was the local high-tech store (think something like an Apple Store or Currys).

You rush to the store and see an all-too-familiar scene. Hundreds of police cars have surround the store, with their officers holding their guns. A few army vehicles are present too, with their soldiers taking up positions alongside the police officers. Bomb disposal teams are also present.

In the middle, you see a scene similar to those which have appeared on television in the past few months. A group of unarmed, masked men wearing gloves stand lazily outside the store and chat among themselves. These are the Criminals. There are explosives on the windows of the store. There are explosives on the ground surrounding the store. There are explosives on the bodies of the Criminals.

Their demands are simple. They want --some amount high amount of money-- transferred to a Swiss bank account within the hour otherwise they'll detonate the explosives.

Despite all of the manpower which is present, the Criminals will walk out of here freely and won't be arrested. Why? Every option available will result in the store being decimated.

If you try arresting them, they'll manually set off the explosives. To prepare for the possibility that they're overpowered, they've placed motion sensors around the store so that if anyone approaches them, the explosives are automatically set off. They've attached monitors to their bodies which monitor their heartbeats, so if they're killed (by sniping or other methods), the explosives will be automatically detonated. If EMPs are used against them, their backup generator kick in and the explosives will explode.

If the money is transferred, they will simply walk out (note: the explosives won't be deactivated). The Criminals say that if they notice any attempts to follow them, the explosives will be detonated. They simply want to leave in a nondescript vehicle (with no reg plates) which they've parked outside. Once the Criminals have left, the police are free to do whatever they want (note: the bomb disposal teams first have to deactivate the bombs).

They can't be allowed to escape. Not this time.

**But, how do you stop them? How do you stop them from taking anything of high-value as a hostage and demanding a ransom? Also, what limitations would they face when choosing targets?**

Note: (I'll add to this bit if needed)

1. The world is just like ours (i.e. no magic or sci-fi elements)
2. I'm looking for ways for the authorities to solve situation *in the present*. Obviously, I could get the secret services of the world and Interpol on the case but that's not the point here. I'm not looking for answers which essentially say 'Identify the Criminals', because that's not possible in my world (long story).
3. Think of this 'method' as a franchisee. A criminal mastermind realised years back that, in this situation, the police can't do anything, so the criminal can walk free afterwards. This 'method' is public and criminal gangs across the country can implement it by themselves. The Criminals are just one such gang. So I'm looking for flaws in the *method* itself, not involving the Criminals.

(I wasn't feeling particularly creative when I named them 'The Criminals', so just think of the name as a placeholder :) )

(Also, please edit the tags if necessary as I wasn't entirely sure as to which tags to use)

Comment: Please can any (potential) downvoters explain why they're (thinking of) doing so?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this seems like a "solve this plot puzzle" question rather than _world building_.

Comment: @mattdm I'm trying to find any plot holes in my plan before I write it, but I understand your point. But, surely this is the right site for it? (even if the tags are wrong)

Comment: Also, the use of the word "[decimated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decimated)" is hurting the pedant in me....

Comment: @mattdm Definition 3b?

Comment: Wouldn't the right place be the Writers SE?

Comment: @Adi219 Pedants hate definition 3b.

Comment: @MiguelBartelsman Maybe, but it's likely to be hammered down there as Writers SE (at least in my experience) seems to be a place where people ask questions related to writing in general or certain features of writing (and not for finding plotholes).

Comment: @mattdm. definition 2 is my favourite though, all that fuss and you're going to *tax* them?

Comment: If I may recommend, I think the solution is research.  This *is* the job description for hostage negotiators.  What you describe is the exact job they have to do: resolve the situation without anyone getting hurt.  Their entire job is to resolve these situations without encouraging more criminals to do the same.  And hostage situations are are *dramatically* more difficult than merely threatening to destroy a few million dollars of real estate.

Comment: Also, as a less in depth research: I recommend watching the movie *Swordfish*.

Comment: As Mattdm said, theres every reason to not go into their demands and all the reason to make it fail. You pay a hostage taker to not do something bad, but if that action makes others do that exact thing you've just shot yourself in the foot as more and more people will do it and SOMEONE is going to mess up and cause a bloodbath/destruction anyway. The best course of action is to either wait them our or send a message to all the other teams that this has to end by straight up shooting one (in the leg or something) so other teams might think twice about the sudden turn in policy.

Comment: See "Somali pirates" for a real world instance.

Comment: I always liked definition 6 myself. Be that as it may, @Adi219 this really isn't the forum for this question. Whether or not you'll get shot down on the writing forum, that's really your best bet. Although what kinds of questions are allowed here is a pretty loose assortment, story based questions like this are very much frowned upon. If there is a specific world-building related question you'd ever like to address regarding your setting or world, then please feel free to ask that!

Comment: "I'm trying to find any plot holes in my plan before I write it" - this is not what this site is for. We can't generate your story for you (and we won't), but if you already have a plan that the police will use to stop the criminals, and post that here, we can reality check your plan to stop them (to a degree)

Answer (score 4):

Uh: you wait, and call their bluff. Are they really going to blow themselves up in an hour? Fine — the Apple Store has insurance. If the Criminals decide they don't want to die after all, they can either surrender, or keep up their threat.  But for how long? The police can work in shifts. They can keep this up forever if need be. How many days of rations does the Apple Store normally have?

**In your question, the "high value target" is just *stuff*. This is an easy call. The risk to that stuff is much lower than the total societal cost of letting them pull this crap.**

You say that this is a "franchise" operation intended to be repeated. This *absolutely* removes cooperation as even a consideration, because — as is your concern — the downside to that is perpetual repetition. **So, this is not a situation where the Criminals *ever* get their demands met.** Given that, as a potential restaurateur, would you buy into a McDonald's franchise if, not only did it involve putting your life at risk, but in the first franchise the whole thing burned down with the owner inside?

Now, if instead of the Apple Store, we've got this situation at *an orphanage*, it gets a lot more complicated. Especially if the Criminals are demonstrably willing to kill babies. Then, someone is going to make a call. That call *won't* be "okay, let them go free as they demand", though, because *there is no reason to trust these guys who are willing to kill babies*. It'll probably be the same "wait them out" plan, until the Criminals demonstrate that they are actually going to kill the babies for sure. At that point, someone may decide that action is better than inaction — there will probably be a raid.

There will be fatalities, and afterwards, a lot of recriminations and investigation, but it's not like there a lot of good options and it's likely that that call would be made again in the same situation in the future. As a reference, check out the [2002 Moscow theater hostage crisis](https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/hostage-crisis-in-moscow-theater) — authorities tried to use a narcotic gas, and 120 hostages died.

Of course, this is the basic crisis of, like, nine million action movies [*cough*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TQ-pOvI6Xo). And probably twice that many paperback thrillers. The plot then revolves around finding whatever loophole or weakness exists in the Criminals' plan — usually some detail of technology, or the building layout, or whatever. But there isn't a general *worldbuilding* answer to that. You've got to write one in to *your* story, if that's what you want.

I'd argue that it's really been done to death and there isn't much more of interest to explore. That's because there *is* a flaw in the method itself: **there are only two possible outcomes**. Most likely, as they are in this for the money and not ideology, the Criminals decide that they don't want to die over this, after all, and **surrender**. Or, if they don't, a response team rushes in and one way or another the Criminals **all die**. "The Criminals get what they're asking for" just ***isn't on the table***.

Comment: I like this approach :) But, there's a few problems. First, let's say that these people are willing to be martyred (as in willing-to-die-in-the-name-of-God sort of die), then you know they're not bluffing. Also (I'll edit this bit in), they operate as part of a wider network of criminals, meaning that even if these guys blow themselves up, the problem isn't solved. I'm not willing to go for a solution where you wait for the whole criminal network to blow themselves up before saying that the problem's solved. ...

Comment: ... Also, the money they're demanding isn't unreasonable (it's not like £1m with an Apple Store as a hostage). Say the total value of the items inside the store is £100k, then the Criminals will ask for something like £50k (i.e. the cost to society will be more than letting them walk away);

Comment: The terrorists at the moscow theater were quite willing to sacrifice themselves as martyrs, too, and it didn't stop Putin from ordering the blitz

Comment: The hardline approach is even _more_ likely (and most effective) if there is a wider organization. This is what I meant by the "total cost of letting them pull this crap" line. If this succeeds, they'll definitely do it again with higher and higher stakes. If it doesn't, well, they'll have to find something else. Unless the Criminals are phenomenally stubborn — or actually are _the Terrorists_ and blowing up everything is actually part of what they want anyway — they're not going to repeat.

Comment: That makes sense, but see the third point in the Notes section. (I didn't explain it very well here :( ) TL:DR I'm looking for a flaw in the method itself, not stuff to do with the Criminals.

Comment: The bigger you go, the more likely a hard-line response makes sense. I mean, assuming we keep the babies, eventually you're making it into a large-scale [trolley problem](http://www.trolleydilemma.com/) — do we make an intentional sacrifice of a few to save millions? That's a decision governments make all the time, and usually immediate violence is the chosen answer.

Comment: @mattdm But those sacrifices are one-off meaning that the public considers those acceptable. What if a government had to repeatedly make these sacrifices? That's the problem here. Even if the Criminals blow themselves up, other gangs can easily follow their method and pose the same threat.

Comment: _Why would they, when they see it doesn't work?_

Comment: Here's another way to think about this: why doesn't this happen all the time in real life? Sure, there's some expense and required smarts, but there are plenty of criminal organization with money and expertise. The orphanage scenario requires a level of evil which is actually quite rare. But why not the Apple Store all the time? Because _this_.

Comment: By 'this', I'm assuming you're referring to the italicized text at the end of your answer. If I'm correct ... sure, the Criminals will die, but the whole place will get blown up. Moreover, this won't stop other gangs from using the same technique. Of course, the government could let the gangs blow themselves up every time, but it would come at a high cost. Also, if tourist attractions or even shopping centres were targeted this way, sending a response team simply wouldn't be an option as there would be massive civilian casualties.

Comment: I just don't get where you're finding all these gangs who enjoy blowing themselves up when they see there is no return.

Comment: And if your answers is _oh, they're not actually Criminals, but Terrorists_, let me submit that, uh, yeah, this is an [unsolved problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terrorist_incidents_in_2018). But it's also a very different situation.

Comment: That's the point. They see *massive* returns as in 95%% of cases the parties involved can't risk the costs of the target being blown up so they pay the ransoms, meaning that it's very likely that there would be many, many gangs willing to do this.

Comment: Also, they're not terrorists... (I said that 'Criminals' was just a placeholder for a name of a gang)

Comment: Okay, if you're going to make "yeah, this works 95% of the time" one of the preconditions, then, sure. But it won't. It won't work 1% of the time, because _that's not what happens_.

Comment: True, 1% of the time, gangs will be forced to blow themselves up, but that wouldn't stop other gangs as the potential profits significantly outweigh the risks.

Comment: Noonnnnonoooo. I mean, in reality, it won't even be successful even 1% of the time. The two outcomes are "the criminals blow themselves up" and "the criminals surrender and are arrested". As I detail in the answer, "the criminals get what they want" is not ever seriously considered.

Comment: Ohhh, see my other comment to you then.

Comment: @mattdm: "Terrorists" doesn't really work either, as most such would pesumably like to be around to see their goals achieved.  Perhaps you mean "jihadists" (or fanatical devotees of other religions) who really, truely believe that by killing themselves and a bunch of infidels they'll go directly to Paradise and get the 72 virgins or whatever other reward their religion promises to martyrs.

Answer (score 3):

All this has happened before...

Bombing campaigns have occurred in the past and are still occurring today.  They are mostly conducted by people motivated by convictions that they are willing to die for rather than simple greed.  This is appropriate, because dying as a result of participating in a bombing campaign is a highly probable outcome.

You have described a situation where a group of greedy criminals have built and deployed bombs on the ground and around themselves that will be triggered if (a) any of them activates their manual switch; (b) the heart rate monitor of any of them fails to show a heartbeat; or (c) any motion detector around the building picks up something that might be movement.  All it takes is one faulty device, or one accident with a manual switch, one dodgy contact that stops registering heartbeats or one piece of windblown rubbish triggering a motion detector and the entire band of criminals is blown up without the authorities lifting a finger.  It is quite likely that this will happen before they leave their hideout...  Please read about previous terrorist bombing campaigns - at one point the PIRA were building increasingly complicated devices to target the bomb squad operators when they tried to defuse devices.  The PIRA gave up when they started losing too many bomb-makers accidentally blowing themselves up while trying to make complicated tamper-proof bombs.  Anyone who can set up a series of devices like this that will always detonate when they should and never detonate when they should not is sufficiently brilliant that they do not need to turn to dodgy criminal enterprises to make lots of money.

The next point has to do with countermeasures - EMPs do not work the way you appear to think they do.  If the area is hit with an EMP then most electronics will be dead - not the batteries, or wires, but the semi-conductors.  If the manual switch for each suicide bomber is on a simple circuit then that will probably still work, so the criminal can pointlessly suicide, but any automatic switching will be disabled.  The Criminals cannot use shielded devices to protect themselves from EMP, because if they are protected from EMP then they are protected from sending or receiving the signals they depend on!  There are also a multitude of other electronic warfare options available depending on how the explosive devices are networked together - blanket jamming if they are only transmitting when sending a detonate signal, spoofing if they are constantly sending "I have not yet detonated" signals to each other.

In addition to dealing with the signals to detonate, there are ways of dealing with the explosive devices themselves - disruptors, anti-materiel rifles etc.  There are related ways to deal with criminals non-lethally.  Or lethally with headshots - the heart will not stop instantly, which buys time to deal with the explosives.

The next point is that the Criminals can say that they do not want the police to follow them, but in today's era of aerial surveillance drones they will be followed, probably in a way that cannot be detected.  In some cities there is no need for drones even - they can be constantly tracked by existing CCTV cameras.  They can also hope that the Swiss bank will let them do some funky financial magic and let their money become untraceable, but I do not believe that the Swiss are quite that accommodating to blatant criminals any longer.

Finally we arrive at the points that Valerio Pastore and mattdm made - after the bitter lessons of the sixties and seventies, all governments know that they are better off wearing the pain from decisively eliminating a terror threat rather than being soft and thus inviting future attacks.  The first time this is tried will be the last.  The government will be happy to negotiate for a prolonged period (gives them more time to evacuate the area and prepare countermeasures) but they will not let the Criminals get away.  They may let them think they are getting away in order to isolate and contain the threat (fake the notification that the money was transferred etc), but the Criminals will end up in prison or as a fine pink mist.

Answer (score 1):

Good! So these guys are already known, so authorities know they're serious.

Remember when Putin ordered a blitz in a hostage-filled theater? And the civilian casualties? And the fact that Putin didn't give a damn because he was fighting terrorists?

Excellent! In the Trump era the Criminals will be just killed as terrorists. Just feed the media the story that the ubersafe plan has a weak point so to justify a blitz, shoot them and...whoops, sorry guys, we will help the families but rest assured: these terrorists won't harm anyone else

**And if this is not our world, then the whole point of a solution to this drama is moot: authorities can react any way they want, since this is your world, it is your story, just write yourself out of this corner. In our world, authorities would likely run the risk and sacrifice a few to stop forever these criminals**

Comment: For your first point, I'm not quite sure that I understand so I'll state what I meant. I meant that the bombs will still be primed (so that the Criminals still have some leverage over the authorities even after they've left (otherwise there's nothing stopping the authorities from transferring the money and then following the Criminals and arresting them)). For your second point, please see the edit.

Comment: Seeing as you've edited it ... for your first point, *please see the (previous) edit*. I'm not looking for answers which essentially say that you need to identify the Criminals. I'm looking to see if there are any ways in which the authorities can solve the situation *at present*. For your second point, *please see my previous comment*. I've already made it clear that torturing won't work as they'll just detonate the explosives and decimate the whole place.

Comment: Seeing as you've completely changed your answer *again* ... your whole answer is clearly missing the point. I want a *solution*, not a plan which involves in the whole place being blown to smithereens (*even* if the Criminals are killed).

Comment: That *is* a solution: making sure they can't do it *ever* again.

Comment: Heh: I was just _also_ editing a reference to that theater incident into my answer.

Comment: @ValerioPastore That *isn't* a solution. True, it's making sure that they *never* do it again, but it's not stopping them *at present*. The current problem *still* won't be  solved and there will still be a cost.

Comment: See the third point in the Notes section (this is why a blitz won't help)

Comment: That's why I have said "Feed the media a lie", so that the store is blown together with the criminals and with the consulatory prize: They will never do this again

Comment: But that doesn't stop other groups of people from doing the same thing...

Comment: @Adi219 WHYYYY? How many people do you have in your world willing to die over the _potential chance of splitting £50,000 after considerable expenses_?

Comment: I mean, let's say your bombs and radios and failsafes and whatnot cost £40,000. And you've got a gang of five. That gives you a payout of £2000 for all this trouble. Why not just _get a job_?

Comment: The £50k example was oversimplified ... think about it this way. Your average apple store would easily make millions of a currency in a year. This means that you can easily ask for a ransom of £500k-1m. Also, Apple would be willing to pay these ransoms as they wouldn't be happy with their stores being blown up because the police couldn't find a way to stop these gangs/

Comment: They _do_ find a way: they don't let the first one succeed. Bam. Problem solved.

Comment: But, it's quite clear that this method would succeed every time if the gang didn't blow themselves up. So, even if the first time doesn't work, people will see that there's nothing wrong with the method and so could implement the method. After a few times, the government and companies will see the massive losses being incurred as a result of these gangs, and so will stop forcing these gangs to blow themselves.

Comment: _But, it's quite clear that this method would succeed every time if the gang didn't blow themselves up._ NOOOooooooo. In the case where they don't blow themselves up, they get tired, hungry, and eventually arrested.

Comment: No... In those cases, the money will be payed (which is why they're not blowing themselves up), and they'll get away.

Comment: @Adi219 No, it won't, because _the calculations I outline are obvious_. That's exactly why this doesn't happen in the real world.

Comment: @mattdm Which calculations???

Comment: The one I have in bold in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, but the criminals wouldn't be stopped (let alone, forever)...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the great answers referencing real life, I'd like to add that this is a major character aspect of Raven from *Snow Crash*.  Raven is the subject of this beautiful quote from chapter 36.  I've censored the cursing, but the book doesn't:

> Until a man is twenty-five, he still thinks, every so often, that under the right circumstances he could be the baddest motherf----- in the world. If I moved to a martial-arts monastery in China and studied real hard for ten years. If my family was wiped out by Colombian drug dealers and I swore myself to revenge. If I got a fatal disease, had one year to live, and devoted it to wiping out street crime. If I just dropped out and devoted my life to being bad.
>
> Hiro used to feel this way, too, but then he ran into Raven. In a way, this was liberating. He no longer has to worry about being the baddest motherf----- in the world. The position is taken.

How did Raven get this level of respect?  Well some of it is the "poor impulse control" tattooed on his forehead in prison when the authorities could not control him (such punishment became a mark of respect once you get out).  But mostly it's because he drove around on a motorcycle with a nuclear bomb in the sidecar, rigged to his heart to explode if his heart ever stopped.  He made a living getting the different corporations to pay him to be elsewhere, in case something goes wrong.

So you *can* get away with this, but you have to think *much* bigger than a bunch of stuff.  The other answers pointed out that, after someone tries this technique a few times, you'll adapt new solutions.  However, if you are the one and only one driving around with a nuclear bomb triggered by your heart, you are a badass motherf-----, and they won't get a chance to learn how to do deal with you.

Comment: Most people (nations, even) don't have access to nuclear bombs :(

Comment: Also people could call Raven's bluff.

Comment: @Adi219 As long as it's a bluff, that works great.